# expat library not found while graph-tool installation on windows 10

Tags: cygwin, graph-tool

I'm trying to install **graph-tool** python library and i run `./configure` in **cygwin** as told here: https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/-/wikis/installation-instructions#generic-instructions and I'm getting `configure: error: expat library not found` although i have already gotten **expat-win32bin-2.2.9.exe** from https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/releases and installed it right next to graph-tool folder. I also added its `/bin` to `$PATH`.

Comment: Where is your python installed?  Can you have two python locations, for example a Window-10 version at c:\program files\python, and maybe a Unix version at $home/user/python  or $home/bin/python ?

Comment: The expact library for cygwin is libexpat-devel : https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/libexpat-devel.html. Assuming you are building for Cygwin and not for Windows

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe and C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe are the only ones i have, also I'm trying to build it for windows

Comment: Expat is part of the python standard library. In python3, just use `import xml.parsers.expat`. See the python help fille or web documention for usage details.

Comment: There are several expat packages that can be installed using the cygwin setup app. The `expat` package has the executables. If you want to build a cygwin exe file, install the `libexpat-devel` package. If you are using the minGW cross-compilers, install `mingw64-i386-expat` or `mingw64-x86_x64-expat` for building a 32-bit or 64-bit executable, respectively.

Comment: If you are willing to use Windows Subsystem for Linux, I'd be interested to hear if the linux version of graph-tool works easily in the WSL, using the conda-forge package for graph-tool: https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/-/wikis/installation-instructions#conda